# How can i convert a String[] into a String[][] in Java?

Tags: java

How can i convert a String[] array into a String[][]? For example, if the String[] was like this: String[] array = new String[]{"Artist,Song,Genre"}; How can i convert that into a String[][] so that "Artist" is in one "cell" e.g String[0][0] = "Artist";

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"a,b,c", "1,2,3", "x,y,z"};

String[][] twoDim = new String[array.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < twoDim.length; i++)
    twoDim[i] = array[i].split(",");

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDim));
```

Prints:

```
[[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3], [x, y, z]]
```

---

Or perhaps this is what you're after:

```
String[][] twoDim = { { "Artist1", "Song1", "Genre1" },
                      { "Artist2", "Song2", "Genre2" },
                      { "Artist3", "Song3", "Genre3" } };
```

Comment: what if the array was populated to more than one index, i would have to implement a for loop how?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
String[][] array = new String[][] {
    new String[] {
        "Artist", "Genre", "Song"
    },
    new String[] {
        "artist1", "genre1", "song1"
    },
    new String[] {
        "artist2", "genre2", "song2"
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need the `new String`s... see my answer.